# Understanding Python / ArcPy code?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy

I am looking for a walk through of the Python code below to explain how it works in ArcGIS.

```
#import modules  
import arcpy, os  

#set env  
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = 1  
ws = r"C:\TestData\Far\FarTest.gdb"  

#make point and poly into feature layer  
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(r"C:\TestData\Far\FarTest.gdb\points", "points")  
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(r"C:\TestData\Far\FarTest.gdb\Polygs", "polys")  

#create cursor  
polyRows = arcpy.SearchCursor("polys")  

#create log to hold ObjectIDs of selected points  
tab = r"C:\TestData\Far\log.txt"  
log = open(tab, "w")  
log.write("ID\n")  

#loop through cursor  
for row in polyRows:  
    #clear all selections  
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("polys", "CLEAR_SELECTION")  
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("points", "CLEAR_SELECTION")  

    #get current ID  
    fid = row.getValue("ObjectID_1")  

    #create SQL expression to select the current row  
    exp = '"ObjectID_1" = ' + str(fid)  

    #select the current polygon  
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("polys", "NEW_SELECTION", exp)  

    #select the points in the current polygon  
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("points", "INTERSECT","polys")  

    #point distance tool  
    arcpy.PointDistance_analysis("points", "points", "in_memory/distance")  

    #sort the point distances  
    arcpy.Sort_management("in_memory/distance","in_memory/sort","DISTANCE DESCENDING","UR")  

    #create empty list  
    fidList = []  

    #send cursor through table  
    sortRows = arcpy.SearchCursor("in_memory/sort")  
    for sortrow in sortRows:  
        #grab the 5 longest distances (this number can be changed depending on the amount of points in each poly)  
        if sortrow.getValue("OBJECTID") < 6:  
            #find the FIDs for the points that have the longest distance between the two  
            a = sortrow.getValue("INPUT_FID")  
            b = sortrow.getValue("NEAR_FID")  
            #append those values to a list  
            fidList.append(a)  
            fidList.append(b)  

    #find the ID that is in the list the most times. This is likely the furthest point from other points  
    farPoint = max(set(fidList), key=fidList.count)  

    log.write(str(farPoint)+"\n")  

    #delete in memory table  
    arcpy.Delete_management("in_memory/distance")  
    arcpy.Delete_management("in_memory/sort")  

    #delete cursor objects  
    del sortrow, sortRows  

#delete cursor objects  
del row, polyRows  

#clear selections  
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("points", "CLEAR_SELECTION")  

#close txt  
log.close()  
print("far IDs found")  

#make table view and join with point layer  
arcpy.MakeTableView_management(tab, "txt")  
arcpy.AddJoin_management("points", "OBJECTID", "txt", "ID", "KEEP_COMMON")  
print("far IDs selected")  

#export final output  
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion("points", ws, "farPoints")  
print("far IDs exported")  

#Delete Layers  
arcpy.Delete_management("polys")  
arcpy.Delete_management("points")  
arcpy.Delete_management("txt")  
arcpy.Delete_management(tab)  

print("Script complete")
```

credit to ldanzinger

Comment: This won't do much of anything without proper indentation. :)

Comment: You could do a lot by just googling the commands that come after "arcpy." using site:webhelp.esri.com in your search.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a site to look for consultants/freelancers.

Answer (score 2):

The script uses a somewhat crude method to guess which point within each polygon is furthest from any of the other points also in that polygon. For each polygon, it calculates the distance between all possible pairs of points, then finds the 5 longest distances and finds the point that was the most common in those 5 pairs.

It writes these "far points" to a log file. It then joins this log file to the original point features and exports the successfully-joined points to a new geodatabase feature class.

Comment: The code became much more readable after your edit, thanks.